# Scroll on keypress (Enter)

Tags: javascript, scroll, onkeypress

I am trying to get my code to scroll on a keypress (enter key 13) to scroll to a section. I would even prefer that when the user types 'launch' (with or without hitting the enter key) it would scroll to the next section. Currently, it scrolls only after hitting the enter key twice.

```
(function ($) {
    document.getElementById("launch").addEventListener("keypress", enterKey);
    function enterKey(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            getInfo();
        }
    } false;

    function getInfo() {
        window.smoothScroll = function (target) {
            var scrollContainer = target;
            do { //find scroll container
                scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
                if (!scrollContainer) return;
                scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
            } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

            var targetY = 0;
            do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
                if (target == scrollContainer) break;
                targetY += target.offsetTop;
            } while (target = target.offsetParent);

            scroll = function (c, a, b, i) {
                i++; if (i > 30) return;
                c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
                setTimeout(function () { scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 5);
            }
            // start scrolling
            scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
        }
    }
```